# Which Latin Translations of Modern Literature Stay True to Classical Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, resource-request

While exploring the [List of Latin translations of modern literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_translations_of_modern_literature), I was drawn to *Hobbitus Ille*, translated by Mark Walker. However, based on reviews from Amazon.com and Texkit, it seems the translation is marred by anglicisms and barbarisms. Given this, are there other novels from this list that I should be wary of? Alternatively, which ones are written in classical Latin?

Comment: This is probably an opinion-based question. Note that, for example, the translations by Avellanus are almost certainly excellent (I haven't read any of them, but he was an outstanding Latinist), but were criticized for being not classical enough in style (to which he gave a [spirited reply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadius_Avellanus#Publications)). *Hobbitus Ille* (the title should be warning enough) on the other hand just seems to be a bad translation.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel, who are the "quattuor primores auctores Romanos" Avellanus is talking about?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Isn't the honorific use of "ille" classical?

Comment: @d_e What do you think? I know of exactly one author that never verged from the true Ciceronian style :P

Comment: @John Not sure what you mean by honorific use of *ille*, but if you mean something like *Xenophon, Socraticus ille* (that well-known Socratic, X.), that's classical enough, but is that what we have here? The English title is not “That well-known Hobbit.”

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I think we do, the title is not "A Hobbit" but "THE Hobbit"

Comment: @John now I shudder to think how our translator would translate "THE History of THE Decline and Fall of THE Roman Empire" ... it's just a definitive article, English has them, Latin doesn't.